# why setup() doesnt work "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined "

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

when i use toLogin in methods it works, but use in setup and return(in this code - **test**) i get error  **Cannot read property 'username' of undefined doesnt work**, why?

```
export default {
  name: "Login",
  setup() {
    const username = ref("");
    const password = ref("");
    const router = useRouter();


    
    const test = async () => {
      console.log(this.username.value)
    }
    return {
      username,
      password,
      router,
      test
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async toLogin() {
      const rep = await axios.post("login", {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      });
      console.log(rep)
      //await this.router.push("/successlogin");
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `this`. Instead, just use `console.log(username.value)`. `username` is already captured in scope for the `test` function to use.

The docs here https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option contain this example:

```js
setup (props) {
  const repositories = ref([])
  const getUserRepositories = async () => {
    repositories.value = await fetchUserRepositories(props.user)
  }

  return {
    repositories,
    getUserRepositories
  }
}
```